# SetDirectory - predefined directory possible?

Tags: files-and-directories

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Relative paths for portable notebooks in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6013/relative-paths-for-portable-notebooks-in-mathematica)

I have a deep subdirectory structure, and the calculations should always be done in one of the deepest subdirectories. Instead of clicking through it using the `SetDirectory` command, is it possible to predefine somehow at the very first beginning of the notebook the second deepest subdirectory as a working directory, so that I can choose with `SetDirectory` just one of the deepest subdirectories?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do this by setting global options:

Navigate to `Format` >> `OptionInspector` select `Global Preferences` and set `NotebookBrowseDirectory` and `NotebookPath`

[image]

Comment: Hi Jagra, thanks a lot, this would be possible. But, to be more flexible, I would not prefer to change some global settings...

Comment: I do the following: inside the directory I would like to be a working directory, create a blank mathematica notebook, and in your .bashrc or .profile, define a global variable that stores the path to the notebook. From the command line, just type `mathematica $pathname/notebookname.nb &` and you will have mathematica launch in the correct working directory. You can then populate the notebook.
 I have tested this in Unix and OS X, and I think something similar might work on Windows. The disadvantage is that this is OS based(and requires you to modify your bashrc)--breaks across machines.