# How to set default save directory for notebooks?

Tags: front-end, files-and-directories

Based on certain [previous](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8778/setdirectory-predefined-directory-possible) [questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6013/relative-paths-for-portable-notebooks-in-mathematica), I figured that if my `NotebookBrowseDirectory` looked like this

```
Options[$FrontEnd, NotebookBrowseDirectory]
{NotebookBrowseDirectory -> "/Users/brian/mma"}
```

then the OSX front end would default to saving new notebooks there.  Instead it defaults to saving them in the home directory `/Users/brian`.  Does there exist a variable I can set to make the UI default to saving into a different directory from my homedir?

Comment: `SetDirectory[dir]` sets the current working directory to dir

Comment: `NotebookBrowseDirectory` works on Windows and Linux, but on Mac, we allow the operating system to assert its natural behavior over such things.  I'm not now so convinced that this was a good idea, but I haven't finished a proper investigation.  So, it's possible this behavior will change in the future.

Comment: @John Fultz I am glad that Mathematica integrates so nicely with OSX. In my opinion it is a elemental feature of OSX that usage of system wide GUI-logic is encouraged and that most programmes out there play within the 'rules'. Examples where custom interfaces are used (e.g. ditching the top menu bar of OSX - like Matlab does) turn out pretty bad in like 99% of the time and just ruin user experience.

Comment: So would an `init.m` with a `SetDirectory[]` command work to do more or less what I want?

Comment: No, what Nasser was suggesting was the opposite of what you're asking.  Since the Kernel and FrontEnd are separate processes in the OS, each has its own notion of the "current directory".  `SetDirectory` sets the current directory for the Kernel.  `NotebookBrowseDirectory` would set this for the front end, but as John points out above the OSX FrontEnd currently ignores that.

Answer (score 3):

On OS X (I'm using 10.9 and Mathematica 9) the file chooser dialogue will remember the last location you used.

So if you Save/Open something to/from `/Users/brian/mma`, then next time you bring up the file chooser it will show the same directory.  This should be convenient.

Per John Fultz's comment above (from Dec 2 '12), it is not possible to set this location on OS X by changing `CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, "NotebookBrowseDirectory"]`.  Quoting the comment:

> `NotebookBrowseDirectory` works on Windows and Linux, but on Mac, we allow the operating system to assert its natural behavior over such things. I'm not now so convinced that this was a good idea, but I haven't finished a proper investigation. So, it's possible this behavior will change in the future.

Comment: "On OS X (I'm using 10.9 and Mathematica 9) the file chooser dialogue will remember the last location you used." — That would be great if it were true, but I am *also* using OS 10.9 and Mathematica 9 and I don't see that behavior at all. Every time I choose "Save as…" or "Open…", the dialog opens to my user folder (`~/`), regardless of the last location I used. Why don't I see the behavior you describe in this answer?

Comment: Or sometimes `~/Documents/`. It's always consistent for a given notebook, but sometimes switches for different notebooks.

Comment: @thecommexokid I don't know.  I tried it again and mine remembers, both with M9.0.1 and M10.0.1 on OS X 10.9.5.  [Try this](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s135/sh/118d3136-a001-4b39-9318-dad73ef731d7/3eea24c498b1fde5cd9868fe6dea7b6d), and restart M, though I don't know if it will help.

Comment: Your suggestion had no effect, alas, but I have better diagnosed the problem. The file-chooser will remember my last save/open location *up to the granularity of the correct item in my Finder sidebar*, but will not remember any sub-directories beyond that. So if I save to `~/Documents/a/` it reopens to `~/Documents/`. If I save to `~/Downloads/a/b/c/` it reopens to `~/Downloads/`.

Comment: The `NotebookBrowseDirectory` setting in `Options for Global Preferences` that you pointed me to in the suggestion you linked *does* get updated to the correct subdirectory each time, though! It's just not where the dialog actually opens to.

Comment: PS, @Szabolcs, is the behavior you originally described documented anywhere?