# Default starting location of "Save as..." dialog in OS X

Tags: front-end, files-and-directories, mac-os-x, save

In the answer to [this previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15552/how-to-set-default-save-directory-for-notebooks), user Szabolcs says

> On OS X (I'm using 10.9 and Mathematica 9) the file chooser dialogue will remember the last location you used.
>
> So if you Save/Open something to/from /Users/brian/mma, then next time you bring up the file chooser it will show the same directory. This should be convenient.

I agree, that does sound convenient.

However, I am *also* using OS 10.9 and Mathematica 9, and this is not the behavior I observe at all. Every time I choose "Save as..." I am back in my user directory (`~/`), regardless of where I last saved a document.

**Edit:** So is the behavior described in that answer I've quoted really what others observe? If so, what's going wrong on my system that I don't see it?

Comment: As developer John Fultz points out in a comment below that question NotebookBrowseDirectory doesn't work on MacOS.

Comment: How is this question different from the previous one?

Comment: @Sjoerd, the accepted answer to that question is that the file chooser will reopen to the last location used, but despite the fact that I'm using the same OS and the same version of Mma as the answerer, I don't see that behavior at all. So the question is essentially, is that answer actually true? If so, why am I not seeing that behavior on my system?

Comment: So you agree the question is the same, but you don't like the accepted answer (BTW: there *was* no accepted answer)? You should have commented there then, and not posted a new question. I'll vote to close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: Fine, commented there. Sometimes I forget that unlike every other online help venue, stackexchange won't accuse me of thread necromancy and yell at me to ask a new question for commenting on a year-old post.