# Difference between Directory[] and NotebookDirectory[] .. a trailing /?

Tags: programming, kernel, function-comparison

The following was the code:

```
Directory[]
NotebookDirectory[]
```

The output was

```
"/media/Dataholder/final"

"/media/Dataholder/final/"
```

In the second case, there is a trailing **"/"** (I am on Mathematica 8 on Ubuntu)

Just curious, why is there a difference ? Is is specific to my machine ?

I found this when this was breaking the code, wherein I wanted to change the working directory to another one relative to the current directory, i.e. using

```
simFldr = Directory[] <> "anotherSubDirectory"
```

Though this sounds trivial, the patchwork needed to get to that directory will be non trivial since I have a code which must work **both on Windows and Unix**.

Any *smart* solution to set the directory to a subdirectory ?

Comment: Maybe this is of help? [Relative paths for portable notebooks in Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6013/relative-paths-for-portable-notebooks-in-mathematica/26311#26311) - i.e. regarding the directory to work on both Windows and Linus, not as a reply to the difference between the two commands.

Comment: Bernd is right, `ToFileName` does not care about `$PathnameSeparator`. Moreover, notice that `Directory[]` is not the same as `NotebookDirectory[]` unless You `SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[]`, well, at least it is so on Win.

Comment: I suppose you can always use `FileNameJoin`. I usually stick with `StringJoin` though as it is so much easier to type. Anyway, an example: `FileNameJoin[{"/Users/", "/Jacob"}]`-> `"/Users/Jacob"`

Comment: Use `FileNameJoin[{Directory[], "lala", "hey", "folder", "file.gif"}]` and forget about it

Comment: Thanks @Rojo for the FileNameJoin.
That solves it 'elegantly'

Answer (score 12):

You can use [`FileNameJoin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FileNameJoin.html) to assemble file names in a robust and platform-independent way.  This will solve the difficulties with the trailing `/`.

---

You can also use `AbsoluteFileName` to bring a path to canonical form. This works only with paths that exist.

For example, to compare `Directory[]` and `NotebookDirectory[]`, you can use

```
AbsoluteFileName@Directory[] === AbsoluteFileName@NotebookDirectory[]
```