# Relative Path in Mathematica

Tags: files-and-directories

I am aware of this question: [Relative paths for portable notebooks in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6013/relative-paths-for-portable-notebooks-in-mathematica/26311#26311)

In the answer it is said that

```
Directory[NotebookDirectory[]]
```

is the equivalent to

```
cd ..
```

Which does not work for me. Directory[] does not take an argument. So what is the correct solution to go to your parent directory?

Comment: You missed the part of an answer, it should be: `SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]`.

Comment: But this does change to the directory where my notebook lies. But I want to go to the one above.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to have the parent directory of the current directory, use

```
ParentDirectory[].
```

The parent directory of your notebook can be found using:

```
ParentDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
```

If you want to set the parent of the notebook directory as the current directory use:

```
SetDirectory[ParentDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]]
```

Note that if you use `NotebookDirectory[]` your notebook has to be saved first (i.e., it doesn't work on an untitled notebook that you just created using File > New)